# Issue with download large file from private_files

Tags: files

I need to distribute large files (say about 1GB or more) in a private_files sections because I do not want unauthorizes download of those files.

However when downloading a file of 1GB from our server equipped with 785MB RAM the download fails (without any warning) before reaching the end.

Someone suggested to me that when downloading from private_files section the complete file(s) was copied into memory before download starts (which off course will not fit for this size)?

Off course I can increase the RAM size, but then again if 2 people start to download large files, it probably is copied both in RAM ending with same result?

Who have experience with this issue and hopefully suggestions or even better a solution for my issue?

Comment: _Someone suggested to me that when downloading from private_files section the complete file(s) was copied into memory before download starts_. Not true, well certainly not true from a Drupal stand-point - `file_transfer()` uses `print fread($fd, 1024);` in a loop, specifically to avoid filling up the memory (there's even a comment directly above that line to confirm the behaviour). Your server may be set up to do something different, but Drupal won't be responsible for filling up the memory

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the server logs?  I wouldn't be surprised if this is a max_execution_time issue.

Comment: As a test I put the file in the public files section which allowed an unauthorized user to download the file just fine. Or does the mentioned max_execution_time not affect downloads from the public files section?

Comment: @Herbiek If PHP is involved, then that may be the issue.  I would set it to -1 as a test and see what happens.  Public files bypass PHP altogether, unless Drupal makes a derivitive (eg, image styles).

Comment: I've just tested the situation with max_execution_time set to -1 and it worked like a charm. What will be a good value to set this on? Max 4 hours downloading (slow connection) means 14400? Thanks MPD for your suggestion!